# Python: Sorting a list of strings by string template?

Tags: python

Say I have a list containing strings that look like this:

```
"00x000s00g00wfds0d"
"dkdf00sdf00sdfg00jk"
"kf00dfjkd0sdl0sd0f0"
```

etc... random letters intermixed with 0's.

but I want to sort them by their 0's. By this I mean, I want the sorted list to look something like this:

```
"00jksdn0sdf00dfgdfvb"
"00sdkml0dfg00egbfnnv"
"00myvcb0xfb00dfgdrhd"
```

Where I arrange things in groups of their relative positions of 0's. Apologies if this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: there's no 'm' in the list containing string but there's a 'm' in 
"00sdkml0dfg00egbfnnv", 
"00myvcb0xfb00dfgdrhd".
please give the output related to the inputs.So that we can understand what you really want?

Comment: Do you mean you need to *group* the strings so that ones with zeros on same positions get placed together?

Comment: It does indeed make little sense, because it appears like you want to alter the input strings instead of just sorting them. More details could help.

Comment: I want to sort my list so that strings with zeroes in the same positions are placed together, yes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by using a key function that returns the pattern of zeros:

```
def zeros_pattern(s):
    return [c == "0" for c in s]

list_of_strings.sort(key=zeros_pattern)
```

Comment: Exactly the approach I was thinking of.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the great tip on just how flexible the key parameter can be.

Answer (score 1):

Regex are a little overkilling, but there's a solution with them too:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda s: [m.start() for m in re.finditer('0', s)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use key keyword on sort or sorted...

```
l=["00x000s00g00wfds0d",
   "dkdf00sdf00sdfg00jk",
   "kf00dfjkd0sdl0sd0f0"]

def stonum(s):
    ll=[]
    for i in s:
        if(i == '0'):
            ll.append('0')
        else:
            ll.append('1')
    return int(''.join(ll),2) 

print sorted(l,key=stonum)
```

**EDIT**

This solution is basically the same as @SvenMarnarch's ...  except his key function is quite a bit more elegant.